# Struts 2 validation not working

Tags: validation, struts2

I am trying to use struts 2 custom validation framework for validations, however that does not seem to be working. I am working on a very big project and the module I'm working on, I'm trying to implement this.

The problem struts 2 is not detecting my `validation.xml`. I tried creating a sample project and  and used this `validation.xml`  and it is working, but the same is not working in the project.

I am using model driven , I hope that should not be the problem.
The basic validations provided by action support are working fine but not my validations.

```xml
<interceptors>
    <interceptor name="multiselect" class="org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor" />
    <interceptor name="browserCachingInterceptor" class="com.comviva.im.ui.interceptor.BrowserCachingInterceptor" />
    <interceptor name="sessionHijackInterceptor" class="com.comviva.im.ui.interceptor.SessionHijackInterceptor" />
    <interceptor name="tokenSession" class="org.apache.struts2.interceptor.TokenSessionStoreInterceptor" />
    <interceptor-stack name="defaultSecurityStack">
        <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack">
            <param name="exception.logEnabled">true</param>
            <param name="exception.logLevel">DEBUG</param>
        </interceptor-ref>
        <interceptor-ref name="tokenSession">
            <param name="excludeMethods">*</param>
        </interceptor-ref>

        <interceptor-ref name="sessionHijackInterceptor" />
        <interceptor-ref name="browserCachingInterceptor" />
    </interceptor-stack>
</interceptors>

<default-interceptor-ref name="defaultSecurityStack"></default-interceptor-ref>
```

The interceptor declaration is also fine.
I tried for days but still cant figure out the problem. the only option remaining is debug.
Can anybody suggest me where should I be looking for. Where is the `validation.xml` file is loaded in `ActionInvocation` so that I can check if validation file was loaded properly or not.

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

    <!DOCTYPE validators PUBLIC "-//Apache Struts//XWork Validator 1.0.3//EN"
        "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/xwork-validator-1.0.3.dtd">
<validators>
  <field name="nodeId">
      <field-validator type="required">
          <message key="errors.required"/>
      </field-validator>
      <field-validator type="int">
          <param name="min">1</param>
          <param name="max">10000</param>
          <message>bar must be between ${min} and ${max}, current value is ${bar}.</message>
      </field-validator>
  </field>
  <field name="selfISDNNumber">
        <field-validator type="required">
          <message key="errors.required"/>
      </field-validator>
  </field>

</validators>
```

This is extract from my action class:

```java
public class NodeAction extends BaseAction implements ModelDriven<NodeConfigurationForm>, ParameterAware ,Preparable {

    NodeConfigurationForm nodeConfigForm = new NodeConfigurationForm();
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(NodeAction.class);
    private NodeConfigurationService configurationService;

    private List<NodeConfiguration> nodeListTable = null;
    Map<String , String[]>  requestParams;
    private int isFallBackChannelEnable;
    private int smsSupportEnable;
    private ServletContext servletContext;
```

MY NodeAction class extends BaseAction which extends ActionSupport which by default is validation aware.So NodeAction should work with custom validations also.
This is extract from my struts.xml regarding actions:

```xml
<action name="createGWNode" method="create" class="com.comviva.im.ui.ussdGateway.action.NodeAction">
    <result name="success" type="tiles">createGWNode</result>
</action>

<action name="addGWNode" method="add" class="com.comviva.im.ui.ussdGateway.action.NodeAction">
    <result name="success" type="chain">listGWNodes</result>
    <result name="input" type="tiles">createGWNode</result>
    <result name="error" type="tiles">createGWNode</result>
</action>

<action name="editGWNode" method="edit" class="com.comviva.im.ui.ussdGateway.action.NodeAction">
    <result name="success" type="tiles">createGWNode</result>
</action>

<action name="updateGWNode" method="update" class="com.comviva.im.ui.ussdGateway.action.NodeAction">
    <result name="success" type="redirect">listGWNodes</result>
    <result name="input" type="tiles">createGWNode</result>
    <result name="error" type="tiles">createGWNode</result>
</action>
```

And this is my jsp

```xml
<s:textfield name="nodeId" required="true" theme="simple" />reado
<s:radio name="status" list="#{'1':'Enable','0':'Disable'}" theme="simple"></s:radio>
<s:textfield name="gwInstanceName" theme="simple" />
<s:textarea name="description" cols="30" rows="2" theme="simple"/>

<s:textfield name="serverIp" theme="simple"/>
<s:textfield name="serverIp" theme="simple" readonly=< s:textfield name="loginUserId" theme="simple"/>
<s:password name="loginPassword" showPassword="true" theme="simple"/>
<s:textfield name=" selfISDNNumber " theme="simple "/>
<s:select name="logLevel " list="logLevelList " theme="simple "/>
```

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't get it: Are you trying to implement a custom validator (in validators.xml) or are you trying to specify validation rules (in validations.xml)?

Comment: @John:I am specifying validation rules. In the debug mode, i tried looking into the validation interceptor and found it has no validation rules loaded for my class.

Comment: How did you name your validation file and where did you put it? Posting the content of the file wouldn't be bad.

Comment: well you won't be able to validate a model driven action without a visitor validator.

Comment: Show your custom validation and how do you use it.

Comment: @John: the file name is NodeAction-validation.xml and my class is NodeAction.java and they are in the same path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found what was going wrong.
The DTD specified in validaiton.xml was wrong. The   specifed  DTD is for 2.3 onwards. I was using struts with a lower version.
I am now using

```
 <!DOCTYPE validators PUBLIC
"-//OpenSymphony Group//XWork Validator 1.0//EN"
"http://www.opensymphony.com/xwork/xwork-validator-1.0.2.dtd">
```

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** Please remove _ Underscore from `selfISDN_num`

Check proper jar files.

Xwork: Core 2.3.16.2 API

And check getter , setters

**Note:** Please check package name in `struts.xml`, does it extend `struts-default`?

```
<package name="Registration" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
... 
</package>
```

Comment: @Partha: See my stack has already included default stack which already has paramsPrepareStack and validationWorkflowStack and so there is no need for me to include these interceptors again(Well i tried that also but it does not work).

Comment: What is your xml name?? `ActionName-validation.xml`?

Comment: its NodeAction-validation.xml

Comment: Are you getting any error in console?? and where did you put your `NodeAction-validation.xml`? It is important to put it in the same **package name** same as action's package name.

Comment: In your jsp what is the name attribute of `nodeId`?? Is it `name="nodeId"` and `name="selfISDN_num"` ?

Comment: Do you have getter setters of both `nodeId` and `selfISDN_num` in `NodeAction.java`??

Comment: Please post action and jsp code. Also specify code for action in `struts.xml`. So We can check if anything is wrong.

Comment: Be default the methods excluded by these workflow and validation interceptors are input,cancel... My action have methods such as list,create,edit,delete,update,add. since these methods are not part of exclude list, so exceptions should be thrown whenever these methods are executed, However this is not happening.  In my sample program, however everything is working ..

Comment: Can you please try with simply putting `<interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" /><interceptor-ref name="paramsPrepareParamsStack" /><interceptor-ref name="validationWorkflowStack" />`? If it doesn't work then we have to put all the `defaultstack` interceptors manually in your `struts.xml`.

Comment: Can you please replace UnderScore _ from `selfISDN_num`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56021/discussion-between-user2757415-and-parth-trivedi).